# Build error running vue.js web application in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-2019

I created a "Basic Vue.js Web Application" in Visual Studio 2019, and as soon as I attempt to run the web application on Chrome (without adding or changing anything at all inside the solution), it notifies me that it was "built with errors". The error shown is: `The Command " npm run build " exited with code 1.` from the file `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets` as you can see in the following image:

[image]

**Log file:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.18.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle vuejs-app2@0.1.0~prebuild: vuejs-app2@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle vuejs-app2@0.1.0~build: vuejs-app2@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle vuejs-app2@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle vuejs-app2@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Bryan2\source\repos\VuejsApp2\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Bryan2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Bryan2\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Bryan2\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle vuejs-app2@0.1.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\Bryan2\source\repos\VuejsApp2
10 silly lifecycle vuejs-app2@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'vue-cli-service build' ]
11 silly lifecycle vuejs-app2@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle vuejs-app2@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: vuejs-app2@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid vuejs-app2@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Bryan2\source\repos\VuejsApp2
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.18.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error vuejs-app2@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the vuejs-app2@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I previously built a vue.js web application from visual code as the frontend while using ASP.NET Core as the backend in Visual Studio 2017 on another machine, and I'm trying to get the knack of Visual Studio 2019 and its updates on my new machine. What could I do to solve this problem?

***EDIT***

Here is the `package.json` as requested:

```
{
  "name": "test1-vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "description": "Test1Vue",
  "author": {
    "name": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.19.2",
    "chart.js": "2.9.3",
    "core-js": "3.6.5",
    "file-saver": "2.0.2",
    "html2canvas": "1.0.0-rc.5",
    "jspdf": "1.4.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "3.5.6",
    "vue": "2.5.17",
    "vue-chartjs": "3.5.0",
    "vue-router": "3.3.4",
    "vuetify": "2.3.4",
    "vuex": "3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "3.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "3.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "4.4.6",
    "@vue/cli-service": "3.0.4",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "4.7.1",
    "sass": "1.26.10",
    "sass-loader": "9.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "2.0.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.5.17",
    "vuetify-loader": "1.3.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2019 automatically installs the project's NPM modules upon opening the generated project. However, the process is relatively **slow** (slower than on command line with Surface Pro, i5-8250U 1.6/1.8 GHz, 8GB RAM), and there is no obvious UI indicator for the installation progress, so it's easy to overlook this pending state.

Oddly, Visual Studio allows you to try starting a build *before* the NPM module installation completes, in which case you'd notice errors related to missing modules (like the one you observed with `vue-cli-service`).

A workaround is to wait until the module installation completes, indicated by the *Output window* or *Solution Explorer*.

### Output window

Open the `Output` window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>, and select `Npm` from the `Show output from` dropdown.

- *Installing:* Notice `Executing command 'npm install'`.

  [image: npm install in progress]
- *Done:* Notice `npm command completed with exit code 0`.

  [image: npm install done]

### Solution Explorer

Open *Solution Exporer* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, and expand the `npm` item.

- *Installing:* Notice the `npm`'s context menu disables `Install npm Packages` and `Update npm Packages`:

  [image: disabled npm menu items]

  ...and the NPM modules are shown with a yellow warning icon and a "(missing)" label:

  [image: missing module icons]
- *Done:* Notice the NPM module icons change to an orange icon, and the label to "(dev)":

  [image: installed module icons]